# Query returning null values

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have 3 tables about medication and stock. The first table is asimple `id` and `med_name` and it is called `medication`.

The second table is about each med and how much do we have pills. The table called `med_pharmacy`.

Third table is how much we give from each med. It is called `consultation_med`.

Now, I created an AJAX request so when we want to give a patient a number of pills, to see if we still have or not before adding to database. If we still have, I will echo `good`, if not I echoed `exceeded`.

Here is the tables:

[image]

My problem is that on initialization, and by that I mean when we get a number of pills per example for medication that have a `med_id = 16`, I will have a new row added to table 2, but not to table 3, because we still not given any pills to any patient.

So when I use the following scripts for the first time for each medication, the button `id=add_more` will stay disabled, because the query is returning null, and table 3 does not have at least one record for this medication. So if I need to give out 20 pills to a patient for the first time, I will not be able to click the button, even I already have 100 pills from the med.

How can I solve that? Should I add an empty row filled with `0` to the field of `given_quantity` on table 3, at each time a new pack of medication came so this problem would be solved ?

```
var calculate = function()
{
  var quant = $('#medication_quantity').val();
  var med_p_id = $("#medication_id").val();
  console.log(med_p_id)
  $.ajax({
    url: '../php/ensureQuantity.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { quant: quant, mid: med_p_id},
    dataType: 'TEXT',
    success:function(resp)
    {
      console.log(resp);
      if(resp=="exceed")
      {
        $("#add_more").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#danger_message").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#add_more").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#danger_message").hide();
      }
    },
    error:function(resp)
    {
      console.log(resp);
    }
  })
}
```

With this PHP code:

```
$cid = $_SESSION['clinic_id'];
$mid = $_POST['mid'];
$quant = $_POST['quant'];
$still=0;
$ensureQuantity = "SELECT
t1.med_pharmacy_id, t1.med_id, 
sum(t2.given_quantity) as given_pills,
t1.med_tablet - ((sum(t2.given_quantity)*t1.med_tablet)/t1.med_pill) as still_tablets,
(t1.med_pill-sum(t2.given_quantity)) as still_pills
FROM med_pharmacy t1, consultation_med t2, medication t3 WHERE (t1.med_pharmacy_id = t2.med_pharmacy_id AND t1.med_id=t3.med_id
AND t1.clinic_id=:cid AND t1.med_pharmacy_id = :mid) 

GROUP BY t1.med_pharmacy_id, t1.med_id,t3.med_name, t1.med_expiry,t1.med_barcode,t1.med_tablet,t1.med_pill,t1.med_received";
$execEnsureQuantity = $conn->prepare($ensureQuantity);
$execEnsureQuantity->bindValue(':cid', $cid);
$execEnsureQuantity->bindValue(':mid', $mid);
$execEnsureQuantity->execute();

$res = $execEnsureQuantity->fetch();

if($res['still_pills']==null || $res['still_pills']=="")
{
    $still = 0;
}
else
{
    $still = $res['still_pills'];
}
if($quant>$still)
{
    echo "exceed";
}
else
{
    echo "good";
}
```

Comment: I think you should use left join(s) in your db query. Furthermore you'll probably need to use more states, not only "exceed" and "good". I'll suggest to send JSON Objects back from php to jQuery. In such an object you can store more information and that will allow you to distinguish between out of stock and never administered. Do not insert unnecessary empty rows in a table

Comment: can you help with the jquery part. I can't know how to fetch single row and send it back to jquery

Comment: or how to use left join so if a table does not exist, we can display with null values

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution as the following:

```
SELECT t1.med_id, 
t1.med_pharmacy_id,
t3.med_name,
t1.med_expiry, 
t1.med_barcode, 
t1.med_tablet, 
t1.med_pill, 
t1.med_received,
sum(t2.given_quantity) as given_pills,
t1.med_tablet - ((ifnull(sum(t2.given_quantity),0)*t1.med_tablet)/t1.med_pill) as still_tablets,
(t1.med_pill-sum(t2.given_quantity)) as still_pills
FROM med_pharmacy t1
LEFT JOIN consultation_med t2 USING (med_pharmacy_id,clinic_id)
LEFT JOIN medication t3 USING (med_id,clinic_id)
WHERE t1.clinic_id=:cid and t1.med_pharmacy_id=:mid  GROUP BY t1.med_pharmacy_id, t1.med_expiry,t1.med_barcode,t1.med_tablet,t1.med_pill,t1.med_received
```

And changing the jQuery script to:

```
var calculate = function()
{
  var quant = $('#medication_quantity').val();
  var med_p_id = $("#medication_id").val();
  console.log(med_p_id)
  $.ajax({
    url: '../php/ensureQuantity.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { quant: quant, mid: med_p_id},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success:function(result)
    {

      var remaining = result['still_pills'];
      if(remaining == null)
      {
        remaining = result['med_pill'];
      }
      if(quant>parseInt(remaining))
      {
        //console.log('1* Quant:'+quant+'_'+remaining);
        $("#add_more").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#danger_message").show();
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('2* Quant:'+quant+'_'+remaining);
        $("#add_more").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#danger_message").hide();
      }
      // if(resp=="exceed")
      // {
      //   $("#add_more").prop('disabled', true);
      //   $("#danger_message").show();
      // }
      // else
      // {
      //   $("#add_more").prop('disabled', false);
      //   $("#danger_message").hide();
      // }
    },
    error:function(result)
    {
      console.log(result);
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#medication_quantity').on('keyup', calculate);
  $('#medication_id').on('change', calculate);
})
```